# ROUND function returns different results SQL Server 2016 compared to prior SQL Server versions

Tags: sql-server

Executed the following statement on databases with SQL Server 2008, SQL 2012, SQL 2014 and SQL Server 2016 compatibility mode.

The results returned by SQL Server 2008, SQL Server 2012 and SQL Server 2014 are the same except for SQL Server 2016.

SQL statement:

```
DECLARE @VarFloat FLOAT    
SET @VarFloat = 1.90255    

SELECT ROUND(@VarFloat, 4) Variable_Float, ROUND(1.90255, 4) Input_Float
```

Results when executed on SQL Server 2008 / 2012 / 2014:

```
Variable_Float         Input_Float
---------------------- -----------
1.9026                 1.90260
```

Results when executed on SQL Server 2016:

```
Variable_Float         Input_Float
---------------------- ------------
1.9025                 1.90260
```

SQL Server 2016 rounds differently from the prior versions, seems to have rounded down the value. Has anyone come across a similar issue?

Thanks!

Comment: It's probably allowed in SQL, but this looks like either a very aggressive and strange performance optimization or an unintentional bug. Note that if `VarFloat` is set to `1.9025500000000001`, it rounds up, so the var is not being truncated to 32 bits or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

Floating point arithmetic is not exact in SQL Server, as well as most other languages, so the slight variations you are seeing are legitimate as far as the standard is concerned.  If you want exact storage, then use either `NUMERIC` or `DECIMAL`.  From the [documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd424925.aspx):

> Note that the decimal and numeric data types are exactly equivalent to each other. Both data types are kept in the product for backwards compatibility. Either data type can be used when you need to store exact numeric data with decimal places

Answer (score 0):

Actually, SQL Server 2016 doesn't round differently then all the others, this might just be a coincidence with this one number. If you were to pick another one the versions might not align at all.

What is happening here is the classic example of why `float` is a "dangerous" format to work with in SQL Server. According to the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/float-and-real-transact-sql):

> Approximate-number data types for use with floating point numeric
>   data. Floating point data is approximate; therefore, not all values in
>   the data type range can be represented exactly. The ISO synonym for
>   real is float(24).

If you want to have exact data with decimal places, you should be using SQL Server [`decimal` data type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/decimal-and-numeric-transact-sql).